# trying to implement the csaf validator service library to the Node.js application

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to implement the Secvisogram CSAF validator service library in the Node.js application.  I need to use the library to validator the JSON Object through a function that returns the "Validate Status" and "Validation Errors".

Here is the lib: https://github.com/secvisogram/csaf-validator-service
Here is the link: https://secvisogram.github.io/

selecting the JSON Editor tab, need to implement this part and you can see the validation and errors towards the right bottom. I am not able to find the solution.

[image]